# Is there a debug memory window in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm debugging a C++ program and cannot find a debug memory window in VSCode. In Visual Studio that debug window is accessible via: Debug -> Windows -> Memory.

Is there such a feature in VSCode and how do we access it?

Comment: Issue still in progress: [Memory viewer when debugging](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/509)

Comment: I saw a glimpse of this memory window in VSCode, but I don't know how to get it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Visual Studio Code does not have a debug memory window.

As mentioned by @zed in a comment, the feature was requested in 2017 here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/509

Answer (score 0):

Memory view is available in VS Code. See: [Viewing and editing binary data](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_viewing-and-editing-binary-data)

Here's how I use it when debugging:

1. Obtain the address of a variable by adding `&var` to the "WATCH" panel;
2. Click the binary icon following the address, and the memory view will pop up.